# computing offset for prev dynamically

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer, kql

I want to set offset for prev dynamically, based on number of items in a group. for e.g

```
T 
| make-series value = sum(value) on timestamp from .. to .. step 5m by customer
| summarize by bin(timestamp,1h), customer
| extend prev_value = prev(value,<offset>)
```

The offset here should be equal to number of distinct customers. How can i compute this offset dynamically

Answer (score 1):

If you can split query into small parts, you can use [`toscalar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/toscalarfunction) function to get number of unique customers.

---

This would be my approach...

```
let tab_series =
    T
    | make-series value = sum(value) on timestamp from .. to .. step 5m by customer
    ;
let no_of_distinct_customers =
    toscalar(tab_series | distinct customer | summarize count())
    ;
tab_series
| summarize by bin(timestamp, 1h), customer
| extend prev_value = prev(value, no_of_distinct_customers)
```

You can find example [here](https://ivalera.home.blog/2020/02/08/microsoft-azure-alerts-using-application-insights-customised-query/).